# "sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/sh sh /bin/bash 1" returns "command not found"

Tags: bash

I've searched all over the web for a solution to this issue, with no success.

I retrieved this command from [this forum answer](https://developer.windriver.com/message/1495).

But this only returns for me:

```
sudo: udpate-alternatives: command not found
```

I did find another forum response that indicated I should install `chkconfig`, which I did install, but I got the same result.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Woah, this software fails if /bin/sh isn't bash? That's what we call bashism, and it's a bug in their software, not something you should be required to work around. You should make sure it's reported as a bug in their bug tracker.

Answer (score 4):

you had a typo:

`udpate-alternatives` should be `update-alternatives`